# Per monitor scaling on Wayland GNOME

Tags: gnome, multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution, wayland

I need to set per monitor scaling in Gnome Wayland. I followed instructions and set `/com/ubuntu/user-interface/scale-factor` to `{'XWAYLAND0': 8, 'XWAYLAND1': 4}`. The object keys are the display keys from xrandr log. The XWAYLAND0 is laptop display and XWAYLAND1 is external monitor. I just want to scale down the external monitor. This seems to do nothing. Any tips?